# Identifying the principal components (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I currently have a 77x12553 dataset consisting of 77 cancer patients with 12553 variables (representing proteins). What I want do do is conduct a principal component analysis and actually identify the principal components within the dataset, so that I can then use the principal components further in my research. The idea is basically to get a matrix or table containing the principal components.I have tried doing this without much success (I'm new to Matlab). So if anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: In "principle" it should be possible.

Comment: you can just reorder your data and do `pca`